# Can "lexical development" and "vocabulary development" be used interchangeably?

Tags: terminology

I haven't quite been able to find the answer to this question online. I'm writing a paper for my first linguistics class and I realized one of the sources that I've been using refers to vocabulary development, but our topic proposal refers and paper refers to lexical development. It is too late to change the topic proposal or the source. Essentially I'm asking if I should keep it as lexical development because it is close enough (or the same thing) or lose the unknown amount of points by not going by the chosen topic on our topic proposal.

Comment: _Lexical development_ **could** cover a wider range of phenomena (e.g, morphology) than _vocabulary development_, but normally they're synonyms. Unless you see evidence to the contrary in the sources, your solution is just to be straight about the terminological variation. At the beginning of the paper, mention both terms and choose one to use, giving your reasons. Don't change the other when it appears in direct quotes (never change anything in direct quotes), but footnote it as meaning the other one, in your opinion.